# how to build query string in magento

Tags: php, magento-1.6

Hi want to build the query string in magento. I tried

```
<?php 
echo $this->getUrl("catalog/category/view",
  array(
    "_use_rewrite"=>false,
    "category"=>$_category->getId(),
    "product"=>$_product->getId()
  )
);
?>
```

i want the url:
`http://www.localhost.com/hungermunch/fujigrill/catalog/category/view?category=11&product=1` 
but im getting

```
http://www.localhost.com/hungermunch/fujigrill/catalog/category/view/category/11/product/1/
```

how can i get the required url . Is it possible

Comment: but why you use rewrite just add what you want after category url

Comment: I want to send the data throug ajax so i think it will be easy for me to do that way.If there is another way for that

Comment: use something like $this->getUrl("catalog/category/view")?product=pid&category=cid

Comment: hi samit rimal i have vote up all ur question and answers ur reputation is now increase from 15 to 57..now happy..

Answer (score 4):

You can also append url querystring params in Magento like this:

```
$params = array(
    '_query' => array(
        'category' => $_category->getId(),
        'product'  => $_product->getId(),
    )
);

echo Mage::getUrl('catalog/category/view', $params);
```

Here's a reference for the getUrl() method:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add on a query string to the end you could use this method:

```
$this->getUrl("catalog/category/view") . "?" .
http_build_query(
    "category" => $_category->getId(),
    "product"  => $_product->getId()
);
```

Although I see no reason not to use your first method, and then get the values from Magento as you need them, for example inside a controller you can do this:

```
$productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
$categoryId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('category');
```

Magento will then get those values for you from the url generated by your code.